# No. of ways 9 prizes can be given to 5 students with a condition

Tags: permutations, combinations

> Number of ways 9 prizes can be given to 5 students if one particular student receives 4 prizes and the rest of the students can get any number of prizes is?

My Attempt:

I got the possibilities for distribution of prizes as,
$(4,0,1,1,3)$
$(4,1,1,1,2)$
$(4,0,0,3,2)$

Solving further includes permutations of the prizes,

$5![\frac{9!}{4!2!3!} + \frac{9!}{4!3!2!} + \frac{9!}{4!2!3!2!}]$

However, solving this gives me a wrong answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Following your approach, the distribution of prizes (we assume that they are distinguishable) should be
$$({\bf 4},1,1,1,2),({\bf 4},0,1,1,3),({\bf 4},0,1,2,2),({\bf 4},0,0,1,4),({\bf 4},0,0,2,3),({\bf 4},0,0,0,5)$$
and including the permutations of the remaining $5$ prizes and of the other $4$ students we obtain
$$\binom{9}{4}\left(\frac{4!}{3!1!}\cdot \frac{5!}{1!1!1!2!}+
\frac{4!}{1!2!1!}\cdot \frac{5!}{0!1!1!3!}+\dots+\frac{4!}{3!1!}\cdot \frac{5!}{0!0!0!5!}\right)=129024.$$
The same result can be obtained in a simpler way as
$$\binom{9}{4}\cdot 4^5=129024$$
where $\binom{9}{4}$ is the number of ways to assign $4$ prizes to the particular student and $4^5$ is the number of ways to give each of the remaining $5$ prizes to one of the other $4$ students.

Comment: But the question says that only 1 child gets 4 prizes. How can we give 2 children 4 prizes?

Comment: It says that "one particular student receives 4 prizes"  not that "one  and only one student receives 4 prizes"

Comment: I did not understand why didn't you simply write $5![\frac{9!}{1!1!1!3!2!}...$ Why did you write $\binom{9}{4}[\frac{4!}{3!1!} . \frac{5!}{1!1!1!2!}...$? And how did you get this?

Comment: $5!\frac{9!}{1!1!1!3!2!}\not=\binom{9}{4}\frac{4!}{3!1!} \frac{5!}{1!1!1!2!}$, you forgot to permute also the $4$ students. Have you read about the simpler way?

Comment: I am still confused.

Comment: I suggest you to follow the easier way: $\binom{9}{4}\cdot 4^5$ where $\binom{9}{4}$ is the number of ways to assign $4$ prizes to the particular student and $4^5$ is the number of ways to give each of the remaining $5$ prizes to one of the other $4$ students.  Is this second approach clear?

Comment: Yes. That's okay. But I am not able to understand the first method.

Comment: The distribution of prizes (4,1,1,1,2) stands for (4,2,1,1,1), (4,1,2,1,1), (4,1,1,2,1), (4,1,1,1,2) which gives $4\cdot 5!/2!=\frac{4!}{3!1!} . \frac{5!}{1!1!1!2!}$.

Comment: Wouldn't the 4 get permuted?

Comment: NO. That is the "particular student". He is given (and fixed in our enumeration).

Comment: Yes, because the statement says that a "particular child" will get 4 prizes (which does not prevent that another student get $4$ prizes). Do you think that my result is not correct?

Comment: No! You are absolutely right. The answer given in my textbook is $\binom{9}{4}4^5$

Comment: Ah, OK. I was not completely sure about the interpretation of the statement of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there are 9 prizes 5 students but one student got 4 prizes [Assume he is particular one,Also assume all prizes are same]
There are 5 Prizes and 4 Students.
Only one student get 5 prizes(5,0,0,0)+(0,5,0,0)+(0,0,5,0)+(0,0,0,5)
So number of ways=4
Now one student got 4 and one got 1 rest got nothing
=factorial_r(4)/factorial_r(2)
That is 12 ways
Now one student got 3,second got 1,third one got 1
Now it is factorial_r(4)/factorial_r(1)
That is 24 ways
Now 3 all got 1 prize and one got 2 it is factorial_r(4)
That is 24 ways
Total= 4+12+24+24
That is 64 ways.
If 4 prizes won by student is not particular then 
4*64= 256 ways
If all prizes were different then it is different story!

Comment: Reading the question carefully is also a skill!

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.